# CreateWindowEx lpParam for button, etc in WM_NCCREATE

Tags: winapi

I pass the pointer to the class wrapper instance pointer for controls as `lpParam` parameter and catch it when receiving `WN_NCCREATE`.

This message does not get send when creating controls like static or button (so far).

So I create a Window, a static and a button, log the pointers of the instances and only one `WN_NCCREATE` message is received with the windows pointer.

My question is: How can I get the passed parameter?

In my previous attempt several years ago, I used an `std::map hwnd -> ptr` which worked fine. In this attempt, I am trying to get a little deeper in WinAPI and try a different approach. Now I'm stuck with this, Google results didn't help much so far.

Should I stick with the map or is there another solution?

Comment: You can't intercept messages sent to system controls without sub-classing them, and by the time you can sub-class a control it's already been created and the `WM_NCCREATE` message has long since been handled. What are you actually trying to do? I'm almost certain there's a better way.

Comment: I am trying to wrap the GUI into classes and use some c++nn features to make a beautiful API. Just some playing around. The instance of each widget has its own wndproc which is responsible for triggering events. An observed field template is responsible for sending and receiving messages then the member is set, etc. To have the member and proc I need to identify the instance so I can pass the message to it's wndproc.

Comment: That is not how event handling in the standard Windows controls work. To do what you want to do will require you to either a) write all the controls from scratch or b) handle events in your containers's window procedures by calling back into the class from there.

Comment: you can use `SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LPARAM)this)` for bind windows controls or your custom windows to class instance pointer

Comment: *you can only use `GWLP_USERDATA` on a window for which you called `RegisterClass()` for; otherwise you do not own that memory. And I assume the OP already is doing that in their top-level window.

Comment: @andlabs - how i know any standard windows controls not used `GWLP_USERDATA` cell. so it free to use for control creator (and only for it)

Comment: To elaborate option b, in libui I have a function `BOOL handleParentMessages(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT *lResult)` that does `WM_COMMAND` and `WM_NOTIFY` processing, telling my abstractions for the controls to fire their event handlers. The controls opt in to this with functions named like `registerWM_COMMANDHandler()`. All my container window procedures then do `LRESULT lr; if (handleParentMessages(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam, &lr)) return lr;`.

Comment: You can see it [here](https://github.com/andlabs/libui/blob/master/windows/events.cpp) and [here](https://github.com/andlabs/libui/blob/master/windows/parent.cpp#L119-L129) (`WM_HSCROLL` is needed for the trackbar control). The above comment is an oversimplification but you get the idea of what you will need to do.

Comment: @RbMm: You are wrong, time upon time. `GWLP_USERDATA` belongs to the class implementation. You cannot use what you do not own. (And please, this time around, don't talk back. Educate yourself instead.)

Comment: @JonathanPotter: You can set up a CBT hook. That way you get to subclass controls **before** `WM_NCCREATE` is sent. That's how MFC attaches C++ classes to `HWND`s, while allowing them to handle the full range of messages.

Comment: @IInspectable - for custom class this is really belongs to the class implementation - he is *owner* of `GWLP_USERDATA` and only *owner* can use this cell. however in case standard windows controls - how i know (if i wrong - can example?) none of the Windows controls use it. so this cell is always 0(free). who can be *owner* in this case ? for my look - code that created the window. so who create - is *owner* because class implementation not use it. if we not create control yourself - we of course can not use it

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041019-00/?p=37533

Comment: @RbMm: The button control in Windows 12 uses `GWLP_USERDATA`. And now try to prove me wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable -  `Windows 12` ? this is what ? windows server 2012 ? if what you say about  button control uses it true - i off course wrong here

Comment: @RbMm: No. Windows 12 is Windows 12. Released probably around 2021. Not sure it'll sink in this time around, but here it goes. [The bonus window bytes at GWLP_USERDATA](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050303-00/?p=36293) *"like the other window extra bytes and the messages in the WM_USER range, belongs to the window class and not to the code that creates the window."*

Comment: @IInspectable - "You cannot use what you do not own." - absolute agree, but how be in case when class implementation abandoned from ownership ? I thought that standard windows control classes ("WC_" named ) never use it and it free for code that created the window( and only it - he become owner) but really this can be changed. you right here - i not found any docs which garantee this (not used by WC_ classes) . and better use `SetWindowSubclass` api here or (my choice) small thunks as window proc, where near code address saved and jump to real windowproc

Answer (score 1):

To do what you are attempting, you can do the following:

- Call [`GetClassInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633578.aspx)/[`GetClassInfoEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633579.aspx) to get the default [`WNDCLASS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576.aspx)/[`WNDCLASSEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577.aspx) registration details for the pre-existing class you are trying to wrap, such as `BUTTON`.
- Change the `WNDCLASS::lpfnWndProc` field to point at your own window message handler, and change the `WNDCLASS::lpszClassName` field to your own custom class name.  Change any other `WNDCLASS` fields as needed.
- Call [`RegisterClass()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633586.aspx)/[`RegisterClassEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587.aspx) with the modified `WNDCLASS/EX`.

Now you can call `CreateWindow/Ex()` using your custom class name, and all creation messages, including `WM_NCCREATE`, will go through your window message handler.

This is how Embarcadero's VCL framework subclasses standard Windows controls.

Also see: [How can I make a WNDPROC or DLGPROC a member of my C++ class?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140203-00/?p=1893/).